# How to campare password if it is encoded in database in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter in my database the password field is encoded using encrypt key but when i want to get login it does not match the password.Name of controller,view and model are Hello,login and user_model respectively.

Here is my *view*:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .text-danger {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function myFun() {
                var r4 = document.getElementById('email').value;
                var r5 = document.getElementById('password').value;
                if (r4 == "") {
                    document.getElementById('f4').style.display = "block";
                    return false;
                }
                else if (r5 == "") {
                    document.getElementById('f5').style.display = "block";
                    return false;
                }
            }
              function myFun4(r) {
                if (r != 0) {
                    document.getElementById('f4').style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            function myFun5(r) {
                if (r != 0) {
                    document.getElementById('f5').style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #99BC99">
        <br>
        <form method="post" action="logindata">
            <table  border='1' align='center'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  onkeyup="myFun4(this.value)">
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
                        <span id="f4" class="text-danger" style="display: none">This Field is required</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  onkeyup="myFun4(this.value)">
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>
                        <span id="f5" class="text-danger" style="display: none">This Field is required</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><button id="submit" name="submit" onclick="return myFun()">Submit</button></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my controller is

```
<?php
class Hello extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('login.php');
    }

    function logindata() {
        $f1 = $this->input->post("email");
        $f2 = $this->input->post("password");
        $encrypt_pwd2 = $this->encrypt->encode($f2);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "Email", "trim|required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required");
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('login');
        } else {
            $data = $this->user_model->get_password($f1, $f2);
            $plainpassword = $this->encrypt->decode($data);
            if ($plainpassword == $f2) {
                $this->dataa['posts'] = $this->user_model->userdata($f1, $f2);
                $this->load->view('home', $this->dataa);
            } else {
                $this->load->view('home');
            }
        }
    }

} ?>
```

and this is my model

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
    }

    function get_password($f1, $f2) {
        $this->db->select('password');
        $this->db->from('user_detail');
        $this->db->where('email', $f1);
        return $this->db->get()->result()->row('password');
    }

    function userdata($f1, $f2) {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('user_detail', array('email' => $f1));
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $dataa[] = $row;
            }
            return is_array($dataa) ? $dataa : array();
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I'm noticing is that you're trying to "encrypt" passwords. 99.99% of the time, this is the wrong thing to do. What you want to do with passwords is use an algorithm designed for password storage.

PHP actually has a very helpful library for this, known as password-hash (http://php.net/password-hash).

When you store the password, you want to use the password_hash function. The following code snippet shows how this is used with the password of "password1!"

```
<?php
    password_hash("password1!", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
?>
```

When this is run, it will produce an output similar to

```
$2y$11$q5MkhSBtlsJcNEVsYh64a.aCluzHnGog7TQAKVmQwO9C8xb.t89F.
```

This is the value you would store in your database.

When attempting to verify whether or not the password is correct, you can use the php password_verify function. This function will return a boolean. If it returns true, you know the user authenticated successfully.

```
<?php
    $original_hash = SOMETHING // this is the hash you have stored in a database
                               // in this case, it would be
                               // $2y$11$q5MkhSBtlsJcNEVsYh64a.aCluzHnGog7TQAKVmQwO9C8xb.t89F.

    if (password_verify('password1!', $original_hash)) {
        echo 'Successful login'; 
        // do normal login things here
    } else {
        echo 'invalid password.';
        // return an error because they had the wrong password
    }
?>
```

PHP has taken a lot of the heavy lifting off of your hands, and you can use this to safely handle passwords.

Comment: Basically, you wish to identify whether your stored password hash corresponds to the new generated hash (it's pattern), but not check if they're equal to one another.

Answer (score 0):

**If your password is retrievable, there's a security flaw in your code!** 
Functions like "get_password" should never exist.

Passwords must be encrypted in a way that the only thing you can do is check if a given input, once encrypted, is similar to what is stored in the database.
@haxim suggests a php library. That might be a good solution - I am not familiar with it. [Mysql has its own hashing methodology](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html):

> MySQL lists user accounts in the user table of the mysql database.
>   Each MySQL account can be assigned a password, although the user table
>   does not store the cleartext version of the password, but a hash value
>   computed from it.
>
> MySQL uses passwords in two phases of client/server communication:
>
> When a client attempts to connect to the server, there is an initial
>   authentication step in which the client must present a password that
>   has a hash value matching the hash value stored in the user table for
>   the account the client wants to use.
>
> After the client connects, it can (if it has sufficient privileges)
>   set or change the password hash for accounts listed in the user table.
>   The client can do this by using the PASSWORD() function to generate a
>   password hash, or by using a password-generating statement (CREATE
>   USER, GRANT, or SET PASSWORD).

There are plenty of articles out there about securing user data. It depends how secure you want your site. But the most basic rule is that a password is not retrievable, and the way to confirm validity is to check if the encrypted input is similar to the encrypted value stored in the database.

Comment: The Mysql hashing methodology is not secure and should not be used for password storage. It does not use an algorithm that is designed for password storage. From what I've read, mysql uses a SHA1 hash of the SHA1 hash of the original password. This is not a secure way of storing password hashes, and tons of rainbow tables exist for this.

Comment: Thanks for that. Does this mean you recommend leaving the encrypting to the back-end code, or can MySQL do the job, just not natively?

For instance, "SELECT users.email from users where md5("password")=users.password" - is that considered secure?

Comment: Yishai, that would not be secure. In that case, you are still only protecting the password using md5, which is not good for protecting passwords. You want to do the authentication at the application level, not the database. You would do something like "SELECT username, passhash from users where username = <<supplied_username>>". Then, in the application you would do the verification of whether the pashhash matches. look at my above answer that shows how to do this.